# Value Error in Spyder in data preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning

I am getting error(ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (10,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,10)) on executing below code....

import pandas as pd,numpy as np,matplotlib as mpl

```
dataset=pd.read_csv("pre-process_datasample.csv")
features=dataset.iloc[:,[0,1,2]].values
label=dataset.iloc[:,[3]].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputerNaN=Imputer(missing_values="NaN",strategy="mean",axis=0)
features[:,[1,2]]=imputerNaN.fit_transform(features[:,[1,2]])

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

label_encoder=LabelEncoder()

features[:,[0]]=label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,[0]])


but when I change following code:
features[:,[0]]=label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,[0]]) to
features[:,0]=label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,0])
I don't get any error....why??? Please Help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a shape mismatch because `features.iloc[:,[0]]` results in array of `array([[num0],[num_1],[num_2],...,[num_9])`which is of shape (10,1).

but `label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,[0]])` results in array of shape(10,)
**so**

- `features[:,[0]].shape`=`(10,1)` and `label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,[0]]).shape`=`(10,)` don't match
- but in case of `features[:,0]` and `label_encoder.fit_transform(features[:,0])` 
  both have shape(10,)

so it is just a **shape mismatch**, simply assigning a dataset of a different shape is not acceptable